# Posts deleted by community review don't have pending flags dismissed

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, flags

Usually, when a post becomes deleted for any reason, all flags on it are automatically dismissed as helpful.

This does not happen when the deletion is caused by 6 people reviewing a low quality post (Recommend Deletion).

[image: pending flag on a deleted post]

In general, the process seems to be a bit off.

- As I said, pending flags hang around after deletion instead of being dismissed.
- It doesn't say who deleted the post. Shouldn't it list the users who voted to delete, or alternatively say "deleted by Community" like it does for spam/offensive flags?
- The deletion isn't recorded in the post's revision history for some reason.

Comment: As for saying who, I think Community should take responsibility for all users who don't have the ability to cast an actual Delete vote, and those who do should be listed along with Community. I do find it a little annoying how these deletions occur.

Comment: We're planning to change how deletions are displayed. At the moment, the plan is to list whoever votes to delete regardless of their rep level. All this information is available in the review queue history anyway (well, 10k+, but still not exactly private), so there's little reason not to display it on the post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem noted in your title was fixed some time ago; I don't know when exactly, but review-deletions *will* dismiss pending Not an Answer or Very Low Quality flags. They won't dismiss "other" flags, since those are presumed to contain potentially-exceptional information that requires a moderator to evaluate.

As of today, the deletion event is recorded as well. For posts deleted by low-rep users via /review, a history entry with a link to the review task is displayed:

[image: Post Deleted From Review]

Of course, the review task displays the names of all users involved in the deletion.

Note that posts deleted by [trusted users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user), even those deleted from within review, will continue to display the names of the voters inline.

Comment: Does this mean it will continue to say "deleted [date]" within the post itself?

Comment: [Example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/832960/eraser-implementation-in-opengl/833874#833874)